# Adding tooltip to rows in treeview in gtkmm

Tags: treeview, tooltip, rows, gtkmm

I am using a `Gtk::TreeView` to create a tree view in `gtkmm`. It has two columns. The first column has two types of icons in different rows. One icon is used to add an element to the tree and the second is used to delete the element from the tree.

I have accessed the column number of the first column and added tooltip to the icons. However, I need different tooltips for both the icons.

A variable `COL_ADD` is used to compare the column using:

```
if (col == _tree.get_column(COL_ADD-1)) {
    set_tooltip_text(_("Add selection to set"));
}
```

where `col` is `Gtk::TreeViewColumn`.

Since both the icons belong to same column, so they are getting the same tooltip. How do I differentiate to get the corresponding rows of icons to add different tooltips to them?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that Gtk::TreeView::set_tooltip_cell() is what you need:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TreeView.html#ae7cc8fde03c481de81fc9d13e34bff98